# Is there any jquery Context Menu plugin smart enought to deal with window borders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I've looked at [UIkit](http://visionmedia.github.com/uikit/), and some other jQuery Context Menu Plugin's but they all tend to behave like this:

[image]

As you can see actual div with menu renders outside the window and so valuable content is not visible.

Is there any way to make a pop up div (say div has id `menu`) auto stick to right border on its own when there is not enough space using jQuery (meaning when it does not fit into current window borders move itself left so that it would appear where needed) like that:

[image]

Comment: play around with `.css({position: 'fixed'})`

Comment: jQueryUI has a position utility that handles collision

Comment: I just can't wait for jQuery UI to get to 1.9 so we can start using their built in menu plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use [this plugin](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) . It will auto-adjust the position to always stay in the viewport

Answer (score 5):

Here is a suggestion that should be implementable to any popup feature (context menu / etc):

During the "right mouse down" event, just capture, and manipulate the x/y if its too close to the screen edge. And "corrects" it to the right value;

The following is just pesudo code.

```
if( pos.x <= menu.width ) {
    pos.x = menu.width;
} else if( pos.x >= screenWidth - menu.width ) {
    pos.x = screenWidth - menu.width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of our projects we are using [this one](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php) for context menu. Works fine.